# Material UI Aligning Checkbox

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How would I go about aligning my checkbox vertically to the Calender element. It's always down to the right where it's supposed to due to padding. Or the invites not aligned.

[image]

```
<Grid item xs={12} >
  <Typography noWrap className={classes.accordionCheckMarkFor} >
    Calender
  </Typography>
  <AccordionActions>
    <Box> 
      <Checkbox />
      <Checkbox />
      <Checkbox >
    </Box>
  </AccordionActions>
</Grid>
```

I tried certain things

```
accordionCheckMarkFor:{
    fontSize:"110%",
    fontWeight: 500,
    float:'left'
},
alignCheckboxes:{
    marginTop:'0px',
    paddingTop:'0px',
}
```

[image]

as well as trying to margintop:auto the container the invites,documents were in [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use flex box:

```
.MuiGrid-root {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

You can check here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2chfxt?file=src%2Fstyle.css

Comment: How would I make the first 3 items stay left and then the next two move to right.

Comment: Firstly the style that I provided in my answer should apply to the grid, not typography. For your question, add this class container {display: flex; } to the parent of the 2 columns and give them a width of 50%.